# Python Pandas multiindex: sort_values by level

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

python 3.11.2 - Pandas 1.5.3

Objective: sort a pd.MultiIndex pd.DataFrame inside each level
Example:

```
    pf = pd.DataFrame({'Feat_1': {('A', 'aa'): 50,
  ('A', 'ab'): 85, ('A', 'ac'): 44, ('B', 'ba'): 31, ('B', 'bb'): 17,
  ('B', 'bc'): 32, ('C', 'ca'): 75, ('C', 'cb'): 33, ('C', 'cc'): 63},})
```

If i do a `pf.sort_values('Feat_1')`, I get:

```
       Feat_1
B   bb  17
    ba  31
    bc  32
C   cb  33
A   ac  44
    aa  50
C   cc  63
    ca  75
A   ab  85
```

Which essentially re-orders the pd.multiIndex, not what I need; I would like to sort the values inside the index levels so that I get this:

```
        Feat_1
A   ac  44
    aa  50
    ab  85
B   bb  17
    ba  31
    bc  32
C   cb  33
    cc  63
    ca  75
```

Answer (score 2):

`sort_values` supports index name, you can name your index levels and sort:

```
pf.rename_axis(index=('g1','g2')).sort_values(['g1','Feat_1'])
```

Output:

```
       Feat_1
g1 g2        
A  ac      44
   aa      50
   ab      85
B  bb      17
   ba      31
   bc      32
C  cb      33
   cc      63
   ca      75
```